# Splash Screen Lingers

Tags: unity-game-engine, splash-screen

I'm using Unity Personal and am therefore required to have a splash screen in my app. I have tried multiple settings combinations, Unity logo 5s + my logo 5s, Unity logo 2s + my Logo 2s, logos sequential and below eachother. Regardless of the combination, the splash screen lingers, only showing the background, no logos, for about 3 seconds. Both logos come and go and then just that bland screen for seemingly no reason. What causes this? Is there a fix for this? I think it really lowers the sense of quality when launching an app.

Comment: What is your platform? Android or iOS or...?

Comment: Does this 3 second delay persist if that last screen is completely empty? (Try with like a red clear color to indicate it has completely loaded.)

Comment: I am using Android 7.1.1, Unity 2018.2.1f1. Yes, the 3 second delay persists with a tranparent, red colour background (which doesn't turn out transparent in the build).